# Can't change to Nativecameraview in OpenCV tutorial 1

Tags: android, opencv

I'm try to use VideoCapture but I can't toggle to the  Nativecameraview in Nexus 7 with android 4.3 
the logchat show me this

> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(4802): initCameraConnect: startPreview() fails. Closing camera connection...
>
> > E/OpenCV::camera(4802): CameraWrapperConnector::connectWrapper ERROR: the initializing function returned false
> >
> > > E/OpenCV::camera(4802): Native_camera returned opening error: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my Nexus 7 is not support NativeCameravie , because it can work on HTC OneX